# php login system do not stop or send any error messages when users login incorrectly

Tags: php, mysql, mysqli, error-handling, login-script

When I coded my php login system (In MySQLi), I get an error that do not actually checks if username or password is wrong, idk what to do abot this. Please help me out here.

```
<?php
// If logged in
    if(isset($_SESSION['user_id'])) {
        header('Location: index.php');
    }else {}
//error_reporting(0);
//MySQLi Login form
    //Database connection
    $con = mysqli_connect('localhost', 'root', '', 'console');

//Actual Login form
        if(isset($_POST['login'])) {
            session_start();
            //Explainging details
                $username = $_POST['username'];
                $password = $_POST['password'];


            //Fetching data
                $result = $con->query("SELECT * FROM users WHERE username='$username' AND password='$password'");
                $row = $result->fetch_array(MYSQLI_BOTH);

            //Logging in
                $_SESSION['user_id'] = $row['user_id'];
                header('Location: index.php');

        }else{
            $wrong = 'Username or password is wrong';
        }
?>
```

Also i got a check.php that redirects you to /notloggedin.php if not logged in, but IF the user is logged in it will display their User_ID, but when user logsIn with wrong details then go to check.php it does not show anything and it does not redirect the users to /notloggedin.php.
So what do I do with that? Is there something I forgot to add, or something i did wrong???
Can you write a example if you have any ideas?? Thanks.

EDIT:
Now instead of using `MySQLi` I got an idea from @christoandrew, so i made everything into functions. What the functions tells the system to do is its gonna check for the username first, if the username exists its gonna make a `$_SESSION()`for the username. Then again using the `$_SESSION()` to find the `User_ID` to the username then its gonna look for the password for the same `User_ID`. Then when its checked everything it will destroy all `'Sessions'` it made and create a `$_SESSION()` for all information like `User_ID`, `Email`, `Username`, `Password`, `Etc..`. Thanks for all the help i got in my way!

Comment: Please use PHP's [built-in functions](http://jayblanchard.net/proper_password_hashing_with_PHP.html) to handle password security. If you're using a PHP version less than 5.5 you can use the `password_hash()` [compatibility pack](https://github.com/ircmaxell/password_compat).

Comment: @JayBlanchard Where do i put in password_hash() ?? Thanks for commenting and trying to help!

Comment: you need to start the session "first", not after you checked for `isset($_SESSION['user_id'])` and error reporting would have told you about it. seeing `error_reporting(0);` being commented out, does not help you and it's set to NOT report.

Comment: If you'll read the links included in the comment you will see how you should use these functions.

Comment: Thanks @JayBlanchard, and @– Fred -ii-! Ill check it out!

Comment: *We aims to please, isn't that right Sam?* @JayBlanchard

Comment: I just took a look at the webpage @JayBlanchard, but im not using PDO or password hashing atm, those will be added later when i know that the login form works, Im sorry if this is annoying but this have never happened to me before now...

Comment: You can do the same hashing with MySQLi, the example is PDO but it works just the same.

Comment: Thanks alot @JayBlanchard, the question is now solved, thanks to @christoandrew! Thanks alot for all the help! I will put in a edit how i solved the question!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

```
if(isset($_POST['login'])) {
            session_start();
            //Explainging details
                $username = $_POST['username'];
                $password = $_POST['password'];


        //Fetching data
            $result = $con->query("SELECT * FROM users WHERE username='$username' AND password='$password'");
            $row = $result->fetch_array(MYSQLI_BOTH);
        // Try checking if there are actually rows that are returned
        // If the rows are greater than zero then the user exists else the
        // user supplied wrong credentials
        if(mysqli_num_rows($row) > 0){ 
           //Logging in
            $_SESSION['user_id'] = $row['user_id'];
            header('Location: index.php');
        }else{
          $wrong = 'Username or password is wrong';
        }


    // The else block below is not necessary and the validation is misplaced
    }
```

Comment: Thank you! Now i made functions to do it all, and also the functions is looking into if username is `stored` in the database, but the password checking was a little bit difficult. when the function checked if the username existed i needed to put a `$_SESSION()` to the username for catching the `user_id` and i put in a if statement that checked if `user_id` is correctly with the username its gonna check for password with the same `user_id`, then if everything was correct its gonna destroy all sessions and recreate them with the same info. Thanks alot for the idea!

Answer (score 0):

you need start the session:

```
session_start();
```

Comment: This would probaly work, but this system i made was ment to work without starting the session for login. Thanks anyway, (This was a litttle too late before i made my new system.)